# using npm in Visual Studio Code doesn't get the fontawesome css files

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-code, font-awesome

I'm new to Angular and running through a Udemy tutorial and trying to install fontawesome using npm.

I used 'npm install fontawesome'
I also tried 'npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free'

[image]

and now when I try to reference the min.css file like the image below I don't have the files. I checked the folder and they don't exist!

Did I not install it correctly?

[image]

Comment: If you tried npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free should not there be an node_modules package with name @fortawesome/fontawesome-free ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way work for me

inslall the fortawesome 5.x package

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

in global style.scss  add this

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

or this

```
@import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

another way by using [cdn](https://fontawesome.com/start)

just add thi like to index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="ano nymous">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdplwg)

Comment: this worked, so how come I needed to use @fortawesome in the styles.css path?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following screenshots. This worked for me:

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

[image: Third image]